# react-native, "abortOnError false" and yet the android build fails due to lint error

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, gradlew, react-native-maps

In my react-native application, building for android I get lint error failure. I want to ignore it but adding the recommended script does not fix the problem and still the build fails

```
./gradlew build

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
```

And have added the recommendation to `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {...}
    defaultConfig {...}
    splits {...}
    signingConfigs {...}
    buildTypes {...}
    packagingOptions {...}

    lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
}
```

Comment: Those settings do not affect third party projects

Answer (score 7):

You should modify *android/build.gradle* instead of *android/app/build.gradle* since `react-native-maps` is a third-party project.

```
allprojects {
    // append here
    afterEvaluate {
        if (getPlugins().hasPlugin('android') ||
            getPlugins().hasPlugin('android-library')) {
            configure(android.lintOptions) {
                abortOnError false
                checkReleaseBuilds false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `./gradlew clean` to configure each project before another build.

Comment: The fact that lint options are ignored for node_module projects, and that this is the only way to apply them to those, has stumped me for days. Thank you!